# .htaccess redirection problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am creating a website using 000webhost.com. This is set up so that mysite.com goes to www.mysite.com, and mysite.com/page goes to mysite.com/under_construction/page. A few problems:

1. mysite.com goes to www.mysite.com/under_construction instead of www.mysite.com (although www.mysite.com does show the contents of under_construction)
2. mysite.com/invalidpage goes to the default error page instead of error.mysite.com/404.
3. error.mysite.com shows up just fine, but www.error.mysite.com brings me to the default error page.

I have the following DNS zone record set up:

www.bossgamerz.cu.cc            CNAME   bossgamerz.cu.cc

```
RewriteEngine On
#Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.error.bossgamerz.cu.cc/404
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.error.bossgamerz.cu.cc/403
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.bossgamerz.cu.cc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !under_construction/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ under_construction/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bossgamerz.cu.cc/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I do not neccesarily need the error messages to be in an error subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules seem to be not in right order and you need to exclude error pages from rewrites. Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 403 /403

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.bossgamerz.cu.cc%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(under_construction|404|403)
RewriteRule ^ under_construction [L]
```